# Display a Form in grayscale

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to Draw any Form (without overridding the Paint method) in grayscale.

If I show a Form in a Modal() Dialog, I wan't do show its parent as grayscale.
I noticed this in the Visual Studio Extension Manager. If a progressbar is downloading a package, the underlying window is grayed out.

I am thinking of this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new Form2())
    {
        SetGrayscale(this, true);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        SetGrayscale(this, false);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Just setting `Form.Enabled = false;` is not what I intended. That does not look as good as a grayscale representation of my form.
I think the `compiz` window decorator for Linux did this with apps that are unresponsive.

Comment: A quick and dirty trick which I use to make a form grayed out is to add an additional control to the form. That control will take  picture of it's parent (`Form.DrawToBitmap()`), manipulate it, use it as background and will maximize to fill the  complete form.

Comment: grayscale, not greyscale

Comment: @Indeera Either is correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Comment: @Kip9000: Depends, British or American English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been said the way to do this is to overlay another control / form on top of your existing form and have it render a grayscale version of this on top, you could either do this using an additional form placed exactly over the original form, or using something like a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) positioned on top of all other controls.

Here is a working example of how you might do this when placing another form exactly over the client area of the first. How to use it

```
using (Grayscale(this))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Implementation

```
public static Form Grayscale(Form tocover)
{
    var frm = new Form
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            ControlBox = false,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None,
            Location = tocover.PointToScreen(tocover.ClientRectangle.Location),
            Size = tocover.ClientSize
        };
    frm.Paint += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var bmp = GetFormImageWithoutBorders(tocover);
            bmp = ConvertToGrayscale(bmp);
            args.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, args.ClipRectangle.Location);
        };

    frm.Show(tocover);
    return frm;
}

private static Bitmap ConvertToGrayscale(Bitmap source)
{
    var bm = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
    for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
        {
            Color c = source.GetPixel(x, y);
            var luma = (int)(c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11);
            bm.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma));
        }
    }
    return bm;
}

private static Bitmap GetControlImage(Control ctl)
{
    var bm = new Bitmap(ctl.Width, ctl.Height);
    ctl.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, ctl.Width, ctl.Height));
    return bm;
}

private static Bitmap GetFormImageWithoutBorders(Form frm)
{
    // Get the form's whole image.
    using (Bitmap wholeForm = GetControlImage(frm))
    {
        // See how far the form's upper left corner is
        // from the upper left corner of its client area.
        Point origin = frm.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        int dx = origin.X - frm.Left;
        int dy = origin.Y - frm.Top;

        // Copy the client area into a new Bitmap.
        int wid = frm.ClientSize.Width;
        int hgt = frm.ClientSize.Height;
        var bm = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(wholeForm, 0, 0,
                new Rectangle(dx, dy, wid, hgt),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return bm;
    }
}
```

Note that:

- The implementation of `Paint` is fairly poor - really it should use double buffering so that the grayscale image is pre-rendered to a buffered graphics context so the Paint method just needs to paint the pre-drawn buffer contents.  See [Custom Drawing Controls in C# – Manual Double Buffering](http://inchoatethoughts.com/custom-drawing-controls-in-c-manual-double-buffering)
- `ConvertToGrayscale` is a tad on the slow side, but can probably be sped up
- Things will go wrong if someone manages to move the original form for any reason
- The image is static, if the base control gets redrawn then ideally the top form should redraw too.  I'm not sure how best to detect when a portion of another form has been invalidated.

If I find the time I'll try and fix some of those problems, but the above at least gives you the general idea.

Note that in WPF this would be a lot easier.

Sources:

- [How to convert a colour image to grayscale](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx)
- [Get the image of a control or form, or a form's client area in C#](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/05/16/get-the-image-of-a-control-or-form-or-a-forms-client-area-in-c.aspx)

Comment: Needs some improvements, but at a first glance that looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it directly - I think all forms are rendered with sRGB.
A hacky way could be to overlay the form with a copy of it as an image (this is simple to do with [Control.DrawToBitMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap)) and then pass it through a simple GDI matrix to desaturate https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this which would work for most simple controls (you would need to recurse into containers to switch all controls correctly).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dialog = new Form())
        {
            Dictionary<Control, Tuple<Color, Color>> oldcolors = new Dictionary<Control, Tuple<Color, Color>>();
            foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                oldcolors.Add(ctl, Tuple.Create(ctl.BackColor, ctl.ForeColor));
                // get rough avg intensity of color
                int bg = (ctl.BackColor.R + ctl.BackColor.G + ctl.BackColor.B) / 3;
                int fg = (ctl.ForeColor.R + ctl.ForeColor.G + ctl.ForeColor.B) / 3;
                ctl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(bg, bg, bg);
                ctl.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(fg, fg, fg);
            }

            dialog.ShowDialog();

            foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                ctl.BackColor = oldcolors[ctl].Item1;
                ctl.ForeColor = oldcolors[ctl].Item2;
            }
        }
    }
```